# Syntax error at or near "DECLARE" in PostgreSQL stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am creating a stored procedure in PostgreSQL 9.6 but I am getting syntax error. I am new to PostgreSQL. Are there more syntax errors in my code?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DBO.Proc_Activity()  
DECLARE
a_sActivityName TYPE  VARCHAR(30); 
a_sActivityDescription TYPE  VARCHAR(2000);  
a_sUserName TYPE  VARCHAR(30);  
a_sErrDesc TYPE  VARCHAR(500);  
   
RETURNS VOID AS $$  
BEGIN  
       
 insert into Activity_Log (sActivityName,sActivityDescription,sError,dCreatedDate,sCreatedBy)values( a_sActivityName ,a_sActivityDescription, a_sErrDesc ,NOW(),a_sUserName)  
   
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And also: how can I call this procedure to test if its working ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes: the `DECLARE` is part of the function body. Also, the `TYPE`s are too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your function like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Proc_Activity()
RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    a_sActivityName VARCHAR; 
    a_sActivityDescription VARCHAR;  
    a_sUserName VARCHAR;  
    a_sErrDesc VARCHAR;  
BEGIN  
 insert into Activity_Log (sActivityName,sActivityDescription,sError,dCreatedDate,sCreatedBy)values( a_sActivityName ,a_sActivityDescription, a_sErrDesc ,NOW(),a_sUserName);  
END;
$$;
```

Documentation : [Create function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createfunction.html)